# Copying UITableViewCells error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, copy

I have a UITableView with about 15 items. I wanted to long press on a cell to view the copy menu item to copy the cell's content and insert it right below the cell where it was copied from. Here's my code;

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView performAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath withSender:(id)sender
{
    // Insert the copied item below the item where it was copied from
    if (action == @selector(copy:)) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        self.copiedColor = cell.textLabel.text;

        [self.colors addObject:self.copiedColor];
        NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0];

        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath withSender:(id)sender
{
    // Show the copy menu item for cells
    if (action == @selector(copy:)) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}
```

The copy menu appears and I can copy the content with no problem. The problem is in the inserting part. It actually inserts the cell but the content is sometimes messed up. For example here I'm copying the color Crimson. It gets copied and the new cell appears under the original one. But notice that another cell with Crimson appears as the last row!

[image]
[image]

And if I copy the color Beige, instead of it getting copying, Aqua gets copied but doesn't appear the it either. It's a other whole mess!

[image]
[image]

Can anyone please tell me how to correct this?

If it's too difficult to understand it by the code and images I've posted, I uploaded a test runnable xcode project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ynnbytoyr353dso/CopyTableViewCells.zip) to demonstrate the issue. Please have a look.

Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this line:

```
[self.colors addObject:self.copiedColor];
```

Should be:

```
[self.colors insertObject: self.copiedColor atIndex: [indexPath row]];
```

Otherwise you keep adding objects at the end of your color array, but in the table view you insert them at a different index so the data source and your table view become out of sync in a way.

Also this line:

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

You can change to simply:

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

For the other strange behavior you are getting. In addition, checking if `cell` is `nil` in your case is not necessary since you have declared a prototype of the cell in your storyboard and the method will not return `nil`.

Comment: Did you try this out?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. Yes I did. It did solve the item adding to the end issue. However there's another problem. Give me a minute. I'll update you.

Comment: Here's the new problem. Say I duplicate [Red](http://i.imgur.com/dkeePkL.png) first. Then [Orange](http://i.imgur.com/DjqjUWi.png). Next I duplicate [Blue](http://i.imgur.com/aFlug0P.png) which is between Red and Orange. Up to now everything works great. Say I duplicate the second [Red](http://i.imgur.com/Gyan05p.png) row and it's messed up again. The second Blue row is gone and there are 3 Orange rows! Sorry if this is too confusing to you. If you have my test project downloaded, it'll be easier for you to reproduce it too. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: I have it, I will check the scenario you described and get back to you.

Comment: It's working! Thank you very much for taking your time to help me out. Btw what's the nil checking part you're referring to? I can't seem to find it in my code.

Comment: You are welcome. It is not in your code, generally dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier could return nil, and you should check if it did and then create the cell explicitly, but since you have created a prototype for your cell in the storyboard the method is guaranteed to not return nil. Just have it in mind if you decide to change your approach one day and not use the storyboard.